# Merge 2 lists of lists, element by element

Tags: python, list

I've 2 lists of list, for example:

```
a = [['a','b','c'],[1,2,3]]
b = [['d','e','f'],[4,5,6]]
```

What I need is:

```
c = [['a','b','c','d','e','f'],[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
```

I can't figure out how to do this, any help is welcome.

Thank you a lot,
Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `zip` for that:

```
list1 = [['a','b','c'],[1,2,3]]
list2 = [['d','e','f'],[4,5,6]]
list3 = [a + b for a, b in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Output of `list3` would be:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: If `list1` and `list2` have different lengths, the remaining portion from it would only merge till the length of the smallest list and ignore the rest of the list from the larger list

Comment: The question doesn't specify the length of the list, and on the example that the OP give's us both list have the same length.

Comment: Yes, I was just saying, that that case is not covered, not sure if that is in the requirements or not

Comment: `itertools.zip_longest` will help in that case.

Comment: If I'm not wrong `itertools.zip_longest` is only available in Python 3.x not in Python 2.x

Comment: @Borja: Python 2 has `izip_longest`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
map(lambda x,y:x+y,a,b)
```

**EDIT:**

This version should work for lists with different number of elements:

```
map(lambda x,y:(x or []) + (y or []),a,b)
```

Comment: If list1 and list2 have different lengths, the remaining portion from it would only merge till the length of the smallest list and ignore the rest of the list from the larger list . Though not sure if that is part of the requirement

Comment: I can't see such requirement in the question, but, yes, it wouldn't work in that case.

Comment: @AnandSKumar See updated answer for code that works with lists of different length.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [['a','b','c'], [1,2,3]]
b = [['d','e','f'], [4,5,6]]  
S=[i+j for i,j in zip(a,b)]
```

Comment: This answer has already been given above. Lets try to avoid duplicate answers.

Comment: At the time I was writing my answer I didn't see the other answers...

Comment: @AnandSKumar There is nothing objectively wrong with a duplicate answer, especially if it's promoting a good solution.